# Failed to connect to database while docker compose keycloak v12.0.4

Tags: java, keycloak, api-gateway, postgresql-11, jhipster-gateway

`I'm composing docker image for keycloak v12.0.4 using command 'sudo docker-compose -f src/main/docker/keycloak.yml up', but at the time of composing image, I'm getting an error"FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database"
I'm using postgresql 11.2 docker image. Database name : rsm_dev_db and I have created a schema keycloak inside it.

Keycloak.yml file :

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:12.0.4
    command:
      [
        '-b',
        '0.0.0.0',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=IGNORE_EXISTING',
        '-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000',
        '-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled',
      ]
    volumes:
      - ./realm-config:/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - DB_VENDOR=postgres
      - DB_ADDR=172.17.0.1
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_DATABASE=rms_dev_db
      - DB_USER=kpit
      - DB_PASSWORD=kpit1234
      - DB_SCHEMA=keycloak
      # - JDBC_PARAMS="currentSchema=keycloak"
    ports:
      - 9080:9080
      - 9443:9443
      - 10990:10990
```

---

application.yml file :

```
zuul: # those values must be configured depending on the application specific needs
  sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie #see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3126
  ignored-headers: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin
  host:
    max-total-connections: 1000
    max-per-route-connections: 100
    connect-timeout-millis: 10000
    socket-timeout-millis: 10000
  prefix: /services
  semaphore:
    max-semaphores: 500
  ignoredServices: 'consul,fmpGateway' # Prevent Consul and the "fmpGateway" app itself from having a Zuul route automatically created for them

ribbon:
    ReadTimeout: 30000
    ConnectTimeout: 30000
# See https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 125000

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /management
      exposure:
        include: ['configprops', 'env', 'health', 'info', 'jhimetrics', 'logfile', 'loggers', 'prometheus', 'threaddump']
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: when-authorized
      roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
    jhimetrics:
      enabled: true
  info:
    git:
      mode: full
  health:
    mail:
      enabled: false # When using the MailService, configure an SMTP server and set this to true
  metrics:
    export:
      # Prometheus is the default metrics backend
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
        step: 60
    enable:
      http: true
      jvm: true
      logback: true
      process: true
      system: true
    distribution:
      percentiles-histogram:
        all: true
      percentiles:
        all: 0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95, 0.99, 1.0
    tags:
      application: ${spring.application.name}
    web:
      server:
        auto-time-requests: true

spring:
  application:
    name: fmpGateway
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        healthCheckPath: /management/health
        instanceId: fmpgateway:${spring.application.instance-id:${random.value}}
        service-name: fmpgateway
      config:
        watch:
          enabled: false
  jmx:
    enabled: false
  data:
    jpa:
      repositories:
        bootstrap-mode: deferred
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    properties:
      hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
        implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
  messages:
    basename: i18n/messages
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  mvc:
    favicon:
      enabled: false
  task:
    execution:
      thread-name-prefix: fmp-gateway-task-
      pool:
        core-size: 2
        max-size: 50
        queue-capacity: 10000
    scheduling:
      thread-name-prefix: fmp-gateway-scheduling-
      pool:
        size: 2
  thymeleaf:
    mode: HTML
  output:
    ansi:
      console-available: true
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: web_app
            client-secret: web_app
  datasource:
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 5
  liquibase:
    enabled: true

server:
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        http-only: true

# Properties to be exposed on the /info management endpoint
info:
  # Comma separated list of profiles that will trigger the ribbon to show
  display-ribbon-on-profiles: 'dev'

# ===================================================================
# JHipster specific properties
#
# Full reference is available at: https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

jhipster:
  clientApp:
    name: 'fmpGatewayApp'
  # By default CORS is disabled. Uncomment to enable.
  cors:
    allowed-origins: "*"
    allowed-methods: "*"
    allowed-headers: "*"
    exposed-headers: "Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count"
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
  mail:
    from: fmpGateway@localhost
  swagger:
    default-include-pattern: /api/.*
    title: fmpGateway API
    description: fmpGateway API documentation
    version: 0.0.1
    terms-of-service-url:
    contact-name:
    contact-url:
    contact-email:
    license:
    license-url:
  security:
    oauth2:
      audience:
        - account
        - api://default
```

---

application-dev.yml file :

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: ERROR
    io.github.jhipster: DEBUG
    com.kpit.fmp.gateway: DEBUG

spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
    include:
      - swagger
      # Uncomment to activate TLS for the dev profile
      #- tls
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true
      additional-exclude: static/**
    livereload:
      enabled: false # we use Webpack dev server + BrowserSync for livereload
  jackson:
    serialization:
      indent-output: true
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        prefer-ip-address: true
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/rms_dev_db?currentSchema=gateway
    username: kpit
    password: kpit1234
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
  jpa:
    database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedPostgreSQL10Dialect
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
      hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
      hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
      hibernate.cache.hazelcast.instance_name: fmpGateway
      hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts: true
      hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_lite_member: true
  liquibase:
    # Remove 'faker' if you do not want the sample data to be loaded automatically
    contexts: dev #, faker
  mail:
    host: localhost
    port: 25
    username:
    password:
  messages:
    cache-duration: PT1S # 1 second, see the ISO 8601 standard
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  sleuth:
    sampler:
      probability: 1 # report 100% of traces
  zipkin: # Use the "zipkin" Maven profile to have the Spring Cloud Zipkin dependencies
    base-url: http://localhost:9411
    enabled: false
    locator:
      discovery:
        enabled: false

server:
  port: 8080

# ===================================================================
# JHipster specific properties
#
# Full reference is available at: https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

jhipster:
  gateway:
    rate-limiting:
      enabled: false
      limit: 100000
      duration-in-seconds: 3600
    authorized-microservices-endpoints: # Access Control Policy, if left empty for a route, all endpoints will be accessible
      app1: /api,/v2/api-docs # recommended dev configuration
  cache: # Cache configuration
    hazelcast: # Hazelcast distributed cache
      time-to-live-seconds: 3600
      backup-count: 1
      management-center: # Full reference is available at: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/management-center/3.9/manual/html/Deploying_and_Starting.html
        enabled: false
        update-interval: 3
        url: http://localhost:8180/hazelcast-mancenter
  # CORS is only enabled by default with the "dev" profile, so BrowserSync can access the API
  cors:
    allowed-origins: "*"
    allowed-methods: "*"
    allowed-headers: "*"
    exposed-headers: "Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count"
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
  mail: # specific JHipster mail property, for standard properties see MailProperties
    base-url: http://127.0.0.1:8080
  metrics:
    logs: # Reports metrics in the logs
      enabled: false
      report-frequency: 60 # in seconds
  logging:
    use-json-format: false # By default, logs are not in Json format
    logstash: # Forward logs to logstash over a socket, used by LoggingConfiguration
      enabled: false
      host: localhost
      port: 5000
      queue-size: 512
  audit-events:
    retention-period: 30 # Number of days before audit events are deleted.
```

[image]

I started postgres container before composing keycloak image but still getting an error.`